# How can I use the new raycast in Roblox Studio?

Tags: roblox, raycasting

I am trying to learn how to use the Raycast system in Roblox studio, I don't have enough experience in Roblox studio to understand what's going on here, or rather how I am going to change or update this line of code since this is deprecated.

```
local function castRay ()
    local origin = firePoint.Position
    local direction = (mouse.Hit.p - firePoint.Position).Unit
    
    direction = direction * gunSettings.range

    local ray = Ray.new(origin, direction)
    local hit, pos = workspace:FindPartOnRayWithIgnoreList(ray, ignoreList)

    replicatedStorage.Replicate:FireServer(tool, origin)
    
    local visual = Instance.new("Part")
    local length = (pos - origin).Magnitude
```

Specifically on *local hit, pos,* this is now deprecated as stated in roblox studio, as well as *local ray*, now I did research that this kind of code can be used instead of the following two that I just mentioned

```
    local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
    raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
```

But the following lines such as length requires pos variable, I don't know how I can move forward thanks to this. So there is no error for now, but I am asking cause I want to implement the new raycast system in this function, and I'm kind of stuck on how to do it, Here is the full code of the function:

```
    local function castRay ()
        local origin = firePoint.Position
        local direction = (mouse.Hit.p - firePoint.Position).Unit
        
        direction = direction * gunSettings.range
    
        local ray = Ray.new(origin, direction)
        local hit, pos = workspace:FindPartOnRayWithIgnoreList(ray, ignoreList)
    
        replicatedStorage.Replicate:FireServer(tool, origin)
        
        local visual = Instance.new("Part")
        local length = (pos - origin).Magnitude
        visual.Anchored = true
        visual.CanCollide = false
        visual.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
        visual.Color = gunSettings.rayColor
        visual.Size = Vector3.new(gunSettings.raySize.X, gunSettings.raySize.Y, length)
        visual.CFrame = CFrame.new(origin, pos)*CFrame.new(0,0,-length/2)
        visual.Parent = workspace.Effects
        debris:AddItem(visual, gunSettings.debrisTime)
        
        return hit, pos, direction, origin
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [WorldRoot:Raycast](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/WorldRoot#Raycast), you'll see a code sample on how to utilize the new raycast function.

The new API just packages the data a little differently. Rather than passing your `ignorelist` into the raycast function, you pass it into the [RaycastParams](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/RaycastParams) object. And all of the data you get back is packaged into a [RaycastResult](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/datatypes/RaycastResult) object.

So you can adapt your code simply like this :

```lua
    local function castRay()
        local origin = firePoint.Position
        local direction = (mouse.Hit.p - firePoint.Position).Unit * gunSettings.range
    
        local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
        raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
        raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = ignoreList

        local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(origin, direction, raycastParams)
        local hit = raycastResult.Instance
        local pos = raycastResult.Position
```

The rest of your code should work just as before.